# WKWebView takeSnapshot doesn't work for WebGL scene

Tags: ios, webgl, wkwebview, ios12

I get a blank image returned when I use the WKWebView method call:

**takeSnapshot**

which otherwise works with a non-webgl scene.

Is there any workaround to do a screengrab of a WebGL scene in a WKWebView (other than passing a request to the webview to use its WebGL canvas to create an image)?

Thanks

Comment: before taking screenshot just add your current WebGL scene to topview controller and make his visibility hide, and then try to take screenshot.

Comment: show how you init webgl

Comment: Have you been able to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think Apple supports screen grabbing WebGL - I ended up requesting a screen grab thought the WebGL scene using a JavaScript call.